# Pipe ffmpeg output to named pipe

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, named-pipes

I'm trying to get ffmpegs output to a named pipe, where I could read from another shell. I do not need the video stream piped, just the informations below to get a state of the conversion process back. I am not able to achieve the piping behavior in any way, but I can write the data to a file with the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i vid.mov -vcodec h264 -acodec aac -strict -2 -y vid.mp4 > fflog.txt 2>&1
```

This leads to the following output in fflog.txt

```
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=   50 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:03.20 bitrate=   0.1kbits/s
frame=   73 fps= 70 q=28.0 size=     230kB time=00:00:04.05 bitrate= 465.4kbits/s
frame=  100 fps= 65 q=28.0 size=     462kB time=00:00:05.44 bitrate= 695.3kbits/s
```

Afterwards I can get lines via

```
tail -f -1 fflog.txt
```

out of the file. But the lines are not escaped correctly, I think. Vi shows me the following:

```
frame=   50 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:03.20 bitrate=   0.1kbits/s
^Mframe=   73 fps= 70 q=28.0 size=     230kB time=00:00:04.05 bitrate= 465.4kbits/s
^Mframe=  100 fps= 65 q=28.0 size=     462kB time=00:00:05.44 bitrate= 695.3kbits/s
^Mframe=  125 fps= 61 q=28.0 size=     608kB time=00:00:06.48 bitrate= 767.5kbits/s
```

So the questions are:

1. How to convert the CRLF to UNIX like LF to return data correctly via tail -n?
2. Or even better: How to pipe the ffmpeg results correctly to a mkfifo named pipe?
3. Or the most general: Is there a different way to achieve my goal in a more clever manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's tackle the line endings first.  `ffmpeg` uses carriage return ('\r') to send the cursor back to the start of the line so it doesn't fill up the terminal with progress messages.  With `tr`, the fix is simple.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov output.webm 2>&1 | tr '\r' '\n'
```

Now you should see each progress line separately.  Things get more interesting if we pipe or redirect somewhere else.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov output.webm 2>&1 | tr '\r' '\n' | cat
```

Notice that the output appears as chunks rather than line-by-line.  If that's not acceptable for your purposes, you can use `stdbuf` to disable `tr`'s output buffering.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov video.webm 2>&1 | stdbuf -o0 tr '\r' '\n' | cat
```

For reading the output from a different shell, a named pipe might work.  However, the pipe won't end until `ffmpeg` finishes, so `tail` won't print anything until then.  You can read a pipe in progress with other tools like `cat` or `grep`, but it's probably easier to just use a plain file.

```
# shell 1
ffmpeg -i input.mov output.webm 2>&1 | stdbuf -o0 tr '\r' '\n' > fflog.txt

# shell 2
tail -f fflog.txt
```